# Python - call super() as attribute of subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, superclass

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Triangle(Point):

    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        """Create a new Triangle with vertices (v1, v2, v3)."""
        self.v1 = super().__init__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
        self.v2 = super().__init__(x=v2[0], y=v2[1])
        self.v3 = super().__init__(x=v3[0], y=v3[1])

tri = Triangle((1,1),(1,10),(1,5))
```

I'm trying call super().__init__() as an attribute of a subclass, however when I execute the above code, I get an error that reads:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Which points to the line where self.v1 is defined in the subclass. Is there something glaringly wrong here? I have tried adding self and other test arguments to the super().__init__() call just to test things out, but I always get the same error.

Comment: Your code works with no error for me in Python 3.6. Are you sure you're running python 3?

Comment: This looks like a python2 error for python3 code.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yup, I don't get an error in [Python 3](https://repl.it/repls/VigorousPromotedDesignmethod), but get one in [Python 2](https://repl.it/repls/GrowingHarmoniousKernel).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that you should be using `super().__new__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])`. By using `__init__` you are just replacing the `x` and `y` attributes in the instance of `Triangle`.

Comment: I was making edits and then testing the code in the same ipython session. I had to restart my ipython session and then it worked. Always something simple...

Comment: @JimWright oops. Yes, you are right! apologies. In OPs code, `tri.v1 is None`. `__new__` would return the object.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah think you need to use `super(Triangle, self).__init__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])` on Python 2.x

Comment: @MatiasCicero That may be the case, but I was just confirming what FHTMitchell was saying. ;)

Comment: @JimWright you are correct about the tri.v1 being none. I assume __new__ would have to written in the Point class before calling it in the Triangle class correct?

Comment: @MarshallMcQuillen `super().__init__` will just run `Point.__init__` on the current `Triangle` instance, i.e. you'll end up with a `tri.x` and a `tri.y`. `__init__` does not return anything, so `tri.v1 == tri.v2 == tri.v3 == None`. You need `super().__new__` because you want to create a whole different instance of the `Point` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code as it is.

`super().__init__` isn't doing what you think it is. On each call to `__init__` you are essentially running `Point.__init__` in the scope of `tri`. If you `print(tri)` you will see that `tri` has both `x` and `y` attributes.

```
tri = Triangle((1,1),(1,10),(1,5))
print(tri.x)  # 1
print(tri.y)  # 5
```

What you actually want to do is create an instance of `Point` for each vertices. To do this and use `super` you can use `self.v1 = super().__new__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])`. `__new__` will construct a new object of `super`'s class and assign that object to `self.v1`.

```
class Triangle(Point):
    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        """Create a new Triangle with vertices (v1, v2, v3)."""
        self.v1 = super().__new__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
tri = Triangle((1,1),(1,10),(1,5))
print(tri.v1)  # Point (x=1, y=1
print(tri.v2)  # Point (x=1, y=10)
```

Now you have a working example, but you could still make is better. Seeing as the only part of `Point` you are using in `Triangle` is `__new__` why should we even inherit from the class? In this case I would remove the inheritance and just create new instances without the call to `super()`.

Also, in python 3 you do not need to inherit from `object`.

```
class Point():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Triangle():

    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        """Create a new Triangle with vertices (v1, v2, v3)."""
        self.v1 = Point(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
        self.v2 = Point(x=v2[0], y=v2[1])
        self.v3 = Point(x=v3[0], y=v3[1])

tri = Triangle((1,1),(1,10),(1,5))
print(tri.v1)  # Point (x=1, y=1
print(tri.v2)  # Point (x=1, y=10)
```

---

As an extra - I would recommend @Oliver's implementation. It is cleaner and not as many objects will be created. The only side effect would be renaming `v1` to `x` etc.

Comment: That was it, thank you. In addition, I realized that the "triangle" I was trying to create was actually a line. Changing the vertices to (1,1), (10,1) and (1,5) is more appropriate for what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Marshall, please see @Oliver's answer as I feel it would be a better implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is not really with `super`, but with inheritance at large.

A class `A` should inherit from a class `B` if an object of `A` is actually defined as an object of `B` with extra properties. Inheritance extends a definition.

In the case of `Triangle` and `Point`, the code you actually want, which has been given in Alexander Kamyanskiy and Jim Wright's answers, does not need inheritance. Furthermore, mathematically a triangle is not a point with extra properties.

Here is an example of inheritance that is meaningful.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

# A point in 3D really is a point in 2D with an extra coordinate
class Point3D(Point)
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.z = z
        super().__init__(x, y)
```

Here is an example of inheritance that while programmatically correct, is not really meaningful.

```
class Plant:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type= type

# Let me check my biology textbooks...
class Animal(Plant):
    def __init__(self, kind, favorite_food):
        self.kind = kind
        # Herbivores only please
        self.favorite_food = Plant(favorite_food)
```

Using another class as attribute does not force you to inherite from it. In the above example, you tell Python that any `Animal` is also an instance of `Plant` which according to my little biology background is incorrect.

Comment: +1 for the simple implementation! I originally used inheritance as it was the approach OP went for, so I focused on fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

when you are called

```
self.v1 = super().__init__(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
```

it calls `__init__()` method of Point class, but doesn't return an instance of Point, it returns None (and adds x,y attribute to your `tri` instance of Triangle class).

To instantiate Triangle with 3 Points code might looks like:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Triangle(object):

    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        """Create a new Triangle with vertices (v1, v2, v3)."""
        self.v1 = Point(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
        self.v2 = Point(x=v2[0], y=v2[1])
        self.v3 = Point(x=v3[0], y=v3[1])

tri = Triangle((1,1),(1,10),(1,5))

     17         self.v1 = Point(x=v1[0], y=v1[1])
---> 18         self.v2 = Point(x=v2[0], y=v2[1])
     19         self.v3 = Point(x=v3[0], y=v3[1])

ipdb> self.v1
<__main__.Point object at 0x7f18c48da048>
ipdb> self.v1.x
1
```

Comment: I would add that the inheritance of Point by Triangle kind of makes no sense here.

Comment: Agree with you, @Olivier